# Take data from html form and send back with flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I want to take data from html form with the python flask and send data back at the same html file. Can you help me with an example or some tips? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use request.form, like the following:

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/path_form_submits_to', methods=['POST'])
def my_handler():
    return request.form.get("field_name", "default value if field isn't there")
```